# Call on not-null type may be reduced-Change call to isEmpty

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I am using below code-

```
editText.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty()
```

and I get below lint warning-

> Call on not-null type may be reduced

When I right click on lint warning, it says-

> Change call to isEmpty

When I check code-

```
@Nullable public Editable getText() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
            return super.getText();
        }
        // A bug pre-P makes getText() crash if called before the first setText due to a cast, so
        // retrieve the editable text.
        return super.getEditableText();
    }
```

that means `editText.text` is nullable

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of the object. Can be called with a null receiver, in which case
 * it returns the string "null".
 */
public fun Any?.toString(): String
```

that means `toString()` can return null

Then how `ediText.text.toString().isEmpty()` is better option as it can throw null pointer exception?

Comment: `toString()` returns `String`, not `String?`. The result isn't nullable - as per the docs - it returns `"null"` for null objects.

Comment: "null".isEmpty() will return false.that means if editText is null , isNullOrEmpty() returns true but isEmpty() returns false..then how lint suggest me to replace isNullOrEmpty() by isEmpty()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `toString()`, the resulting String is never null (hence, `isNullOrEmpty()` == `isEmpty`) - any null values are changed into the string `"null"`.

Since this isn't what you want to be checking, you should stop using `toString()` - just use `isNullOrEmpty()` directly:

```
editText.text.isNullOrEmpty()
```